# Django, total price of not iterable object

Tags: django

Hello I have a question I have no idea how can i get total price of not iterable object in Django, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /cart
'OrderItem' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code, I would be pleased by any advise.

views.py

```
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
order_items = OrderItem.objects.annotate(
    sum=Sum(F('item__price') * F('quantity'))
).get(cart=cart)
order_items.total_price = order_items.sum
order_items.save(force_update=True)
```

models.py

```
class Item(Visits, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price =  models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='static/images/man.png')
    description = models.TextField(default="Item")
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: what line is the error on? Can you add output of `print(dir(order_items))`?

Answer (score 0):

you can create function in you model and used The result on your view
like this:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
# does not needed
# total_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)

@property
def get_total(self):
    total = self.item.price * self.quantity
    return total
```